# React-Redux Project: React elements not rendering, only Parent directory is being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, react-redux

So fortunately, I was able to get my webpack build to work without errors. However, whenever I run 'npm start' (webpack-dev-server), it renders/serves the parent directory of this file. I'm not quite sure why this is the case.

-I created a server.js file in which when I go to the home route '/', it should serve the index.html file to it.
-I made sure the entry in the webpack.config.js file is correct, and it seems to be the case. I included my file structure below as reference as well.

[image]

**client/App.JSX**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Wrapper from './Containers/MainContainer.jsx';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <div id = "app">
            <Wrapper/>
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**client/Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Gifty</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="client/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Hang React App Here -->
        <div id = "app"></div>
        <!-- LOAD SCRIPTS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Server/Server.js**

```
/* eslint no-unused-vars: 0 */
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.json());
// app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/index.html')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile((path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

**Client/Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import App from './App.jsx';
import store from './store.js';
// import styles from './index.css'
// import './index.css';

render(
    <Provider store = {store}>
        <App/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    //start at entry
    entry: './client/index.js',
    // devtool: "eval-source-map",
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
    //Run these rules on it & go through the loaders
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.svg$/, use: 'svg-inline-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
            { test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
                        // plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread']
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    }, 
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
        resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'client/index.html'
        })
    ],  
    devServer: {
        publicPath: "/build/",
        proxy: {
            'api':'http://localhost:3000',
        },
    },  
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
}
```

**Beginning part of package.json**

```
{
  "name": "gift-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack-dev-server --open",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"nodemon server/server.js\" \"webpack-dev-server --open\" "
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
  }
```

**General File Structure**

```
Client
  -Actions
    -actions.js
  -Components
    -component1
    -component2
    -component3
  -Constants
    -actionTypes.js
  -Containers
    -Container1
    -Container2
  -Reducers
    -Reducers (Reducer Logic)
    -Index.js(Combined Reducers)
  
  -App.jsx
  -index.html
  -index.css
  -index.js (Provider & imported store).
  -store.js

-Server
  -server.js
  -models
    -model1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because in `Server/Server.js` you change into the parent directory `'../client/index.html'`?

Comment: Webpack outputs our app into the `dist` folder (same level as `client`). You need to change `server.reder` to serve `../dist/index.html`. Also your `client/client.html` is used as template for webpack, so the script tag in it is not necessary. Wp will auto write the script tag to the output file

Comment: On my server.js file I tried:
```
res.status(200).sendFile((path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html')));
```

But still no luck. It works when I do localhost:8080/client, but it wont render when I enter localhost 8080